# SQL Server 2012 is not using transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

I have a SQL Server 2012 Express.
Now, I have seen, that it is not using the log-file anymore. The size of the log file is always 2MB and the changedate is in the past. The database is in high use so I am wondering me, why the transaction log is not growing. It looks for me, that the SQL Server is not using the logfile anymore.
On the database Autogrowing for the logfile is on (in 10MB steps) and the maximum is 2'097'152MB.
Are there any other options to configure the use of the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I have seen, that it is not using the log-file anymore. The size of the log file is 
>   always 2MB

Technically impossible to not use the tx log.

Somone like did put your database into simple recovery mode, so that log is automatically truncated after every transaction, but it is still used.

Check the recovery settings on the database (in properties).

Comment: I have now changed the recovery model to full. But the log still remains at 2MB and there is no change at the changedate of the file.

Comment: Always nice to see programmers not knowing the OS. The changedate in the file will change when the file gets closed - and a sql data file (including the logs) only gets ever closed when you shut down the server. Make transactions and if the model is full then.... they will record. and take a backup. and remember to truncate the log after full backups and making log backups. Or - just read the documentation.